# Oracle PL/SQL loop issue

Tags: loops, plsql

Hey guys trying to use a loop to cycle though days so my script doesn't fail the loop fails to execute each time I am not sure what I am doing wrong however i know for a fact the select statement is fine and working its just the loop i have trouble with also is it possible to have the loop check the max date in the table delete only the most recent day in case of incomplete data then add only whats needed to date?

Error line 41, column 4:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 7m Column 1:
Pl/sql statement ignored

```
delete Target_table
commit;

DECLARE
   i_date date; 
BEGIN
   i_date := '01-Jan-2014';
WHILE i_date < sysdate LOOP

insert into Target_table
Select field_1,
       field_2
From Data_table_1
LEFT JOIN Data_table_2 
 ON Data_table_1.ACCOUNT_ID=Data_table_2.account_id
 Where Data_table_1.Date >= i_date
         and Data_table_1.Date < i_date+1
         and Data_table_1.COST_CENTRE In ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10')
   And Data_table_1.field_3 In ('C', 'D')
   And Data_table_1.field_4 Is Null
   And Data_table_2.field_5 in (1,2)
   END;
commit;
   i_date := i_date +1;
   END LOOP;
END
```

Comment: Always helpful to post error message. Use DateAdd(): `DATEADD (d, 1, i_date)`. Also, declare `i_date` as 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Comment: i date is initialized as a string. convert it to date `i_date=to_date('01-JAN-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')`

Comment: You don't give all your code. Please rerun agian with this code because error line is not match with your code, and give us your table structure because I think the second error it's about you datatype and number of columns. For this, There are more "END" after insert statement  and There aren't " ; " at your insert statement and last "END".

Comment: the issue is not related to the data type used in i_date i have used the same syntax to declare a date before without issue

Comment: i haven't removed any of the code just cleaned it up to make it easier to read

Comment: suttipong it turns our despite half of your answer being wrong the other half was correct it was the additional end statement that caused me to have the issue if you like  answer and ill award it to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some modifications in your code. I think this should work. I have also mentioned comments for which i have made changes.

```
DECLARE
  i_date DATE;
BEGIN
   DELETE Target_table; -- Inserted inside the Anonymous block
  i_date      := to_date('10-Nov-2015','DD-MON-YYYY'); -- Specified Date format
  WHILE i_date < sysdate
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO Target_table
    SELECT field_1,
      field_2
    FROM Data_table_1
    LEFT JOIN Data_table_2
    ON Data_table_1.ACCOUNT_ID      =Data_table_2.account_id
    WHERE Data_table_1.Date_field1 >= i_date
    AND Data_table_1.Date_field1    < i_date+1
    AND Data_table_1.COST_CENTRE           IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10')
    AND Data_table_1.field_3               IN ('C', 'D')
    AND Data_table_1.field_4       IS NULL
    AND Data_table_2.field_5       IN (1,2);
    dbms_output.put_line(i_date);
    i_date := i_date +1;
  END LOOP;
COMMIT; -- Added commit at the end
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to mention that the most efficent way is write the query in in SQL whenever possible, when PL/SQL can be avoided. (There is an overhead involved in the context switch between SQL and PL/SQL blocks). This is how i would write the query. The new block, using CONNECT by would generate all dates between i_date and sysdate

```
DECLARE
i_date DATE;
BEGIN

DELETE Target_table;

SELECT field_1,
       field_2
   FROM Data_table_1
   JOIN (SELECT i_date + level -1 as i_date_new
          FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL<=TRUNC(sysdate)-i_date
         )dates_generated
      ON Data_table_1.Date_field1 >= dates_generated.i_date_new
     AND Data_table_1.Date_field1    < dates_generated.i_date_new+1
   LEFT JOIN Data_table_2
     ON Data_table_1.ACCOUNT_ID      =Data_table_2.account_id
  WHERE Data_table_1.COST_CENTRE           IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10')
    AND Data_table_1.field_3               IN ('C', 'D')
    AND Data_table_1.field_4       IS NULL
    AND Data_table_2.field_5       IN (1,2);

END;
```